# how to MODIFY a constraint layout programmatically?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Ive got a view like below :

```
 <org.rayanmehr.atlas.shared.customview.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDownVoteCount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/anchorHelper"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/tvDownVoteIcon"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgComment"
    />
```

how can i modify the value of `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias` or any other constraint property programmatically without having top set the whole set of the properties again in my activity ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just found the answer in [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html) and you can use `ConstraintSet` to achieve this like below:

```
ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
constraintSet.clone(context, R.id.activity_constraint);

//for example lets change the vertical bias of tvDownVoteIcon
float biasedValue = 0.2f;
constraintSet.setVerticalBias(R.id.tvDownVoteIcon, biasedValue);

//or change the anchor
constraintSet.connect
(R.id.tvDownVoteIcon,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,R.id.txt,ConstraintSet.RIGHT,0);

//then apply
constraintSet.applyTo( (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_constraint));
```

Answer (score 52):

Here is what I did (no need for `ConstraintSet`, we can work directly on the constraints themselves):

```java
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) myView.getLayoutParams();
params.horizontalBias = 0.2f; // here is one modification for example. modify anything else you want :)
myView.setLayoutParams(params); // request the view to use the new modified params
```

it worked like a charm when I had a `SeekBar` and a `TextView` below it (aligned to it both left+right), and I wanted to update the `TextView` position to be under the `SeekBar`'s cursor, so I had to update the horizontal bias params on the `SeekBar`'s `OnSeekBarChangeListener`

Comment: Thanks a lot man. You just helped a lot. I was having issue settings toptotop of a view. You method worked flawlessly.

Comment: Note: It is completely necessary to call `setLayoutParams()`. Some times, it works even if you don't call it, but not this one.

Comment: Awesome, you saved me

Comment: That is the best answer. for some reason calling requestLayout not working

Answer (score 43):

If you are using Kotlin and you have androidx-core-ktx lib you can simply do:

```
someView.updateLayoutParams<ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams> { horizontalBias = 0.5f }
```

Comment: This was easy and quick. Thanks!

Comment: tnx sir ... very quick and useful 

Comment: this is the answer, so glad I found.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I haven't used this specific functionality. This is just my interpretation on how I would try to do it.

I think that what you need is [`ConstraintSet`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html). After obtaining it, you could modify it and apply it again. This is a relevant example from [this article](https://robinhood.engineering/beautiful-animations-using-android-constraintlayout-eee5b72ecae3).

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    val constraintSet1 = ConstraintSet()
    constraintSet1.clone(constraintLayout)
    val constraintSet2 = ConstraintSet()
    constraintSet2.clone(constraintLayout)
    constraintSet2.centerVertically(R.id.image, 0)

    var changed = false
    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener {
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(constraintLayout)
        val constraint = if (changed) constraintSet1 else constraintSet2
        constraint.applyTo(constraintLayout)
        changed = !changed
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not what i want; i just want to change bias only. actually its toggling between two state !!! not my answer.

Comment: `ConstraintLayout` bases the layout in constraints, which are stored in a `ConstraintSet`. So, you need to alter a `ConstraintSet` in order to modify the bias, you cannot modify the bias directly. Of course, the example that I copied is not modifying specifically the bias, but that's the structure you should follow.

Comment: yes you are true but thats not good to answer questions like this which will make the person who asks more confused. i found the answer myself. anyway thanks a lot to help.