# How to change divider bias programatically

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to change my divider vertical bias programatically and i tried this [how to MODIFY a constraint layout programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45920205/how-to-modify-a-constraint-layout-programmatically) , but none of the solutions worked for me. When i tried it on my divider whole app was reseting, and  want to stay in 2 activity. What should i do ? There are several other dividers connected to the one i'm trying to move, if this changes anything.

Divider xml :

```
    <View
    android:id="@+id/divider2"
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:background="#48B130"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider" />
```

2nd Divider attached to 1st one :

```
    <View
    android:id="@+id/divider3"
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="#48B130"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/divider2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/divider2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/divider2" />
```

2nd activity code(empty) :

```
 public class GRA extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gr);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, you should create a new LayoutParams with your settings and apply to that view.